# MATLAB set class `size` (overload operation upon class)

Tags: matlab

```matlab
classdef Dog
end
```

`d=Dog()`; can `size(d)` be controlled? Is there some `property` to set or `method` to overload?

Ultimately I have like `d.data = [1, 2, 3]` and want `length(d) == 3`. I'm aware I can make `d.length()`. As an aside, is there a list of MATLAB "magic methods", i.e. functions that control interaction with classes, like [subsref](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB, don't think of class method as similar to class methods in other languages. Really, what they are is overloaded versions of a function.

`size(d)` is the same as `d.size()` (which is the same as `d.size`, parentheses are not needed to call a function), if `d` is an object of a custom class and `size` is overloaded for that class.

So, you can define `function size` in the `methods` section of your `classdef`, to overload `size` for your class. You can also create a `size.m` file within a `@Dog/` directory to accomplish the same thing.

For example, if you create a file `@char/size.m` with a function definition inside, you will have overloaded `size` for char arrays.

---

The above is true for *any* function. Some functions, when overloaded, can cause headaches. For example be careful when overloading `numel`, as it could cause indexed assignment expressions to fail. `size` is used by the `whos` command to display variable information, as well as by the similar functionality in the GUI, so it is important to have it behave in the expected way.

The object behavior that you might want to change that is not obviously a function, relates to operators. Each operator is also defined by a function (including `end` in indexing!). See [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html#br02znk-6) for a full list.

Comment: Very informative!